# Perl: Connect to Microsoft Exchange using SOAP

Tags: xml, perl, soap, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I'm not quite sure where to start with this one.  Ideally, I'd like to have a Perl script that connects to my work's Exchange server and queries for all of the conference room schedules.  I believe what I want to accomplish is [this](http://seroter.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/leveraging-exchange-2007-web-services-to-find-open-conference-rooms/).  Only problem is, I'm running on a Mac, and the [Exchange libraries](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35371) are only available on Windows, so I've resorted to trying the SOAP way in Perl.  Only problem is, I don't really know what I'm doing.

I've taken a look at [EWS::Client](http://search.cpan.org/~oliver/EWS-Client-1.113000/lib/EWS/Client.pm), which is excellent... it allows me to connect to the Exchange server and grab events from my calendar.  Only problem is, this module does not have what I'm looking for, so I'm sort of back to square one.  If I can utilize EWS::Client's connection and then somehow send an XML request to the Exchange server, I think I'd have it, but I really have no idea how to do that.

I've started with this connection code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use SOAP::Lite;
use XML::Simple;

my $file = 'email.xml';
my $xml = new XML::Simple;
my $data = $xml->XMLin('email.xml');

my $service = 'https://<domain>/EWS/Services.wsdl';
my $addr = 'https://<domain>/EWS/Exchange.asmx';
my $domain = '<domain>';
my $uname = '<username>';
my $pass = '<password>';
my @ua_args = (keep_alive => 1);
my @creds = ($domain, '', $uname, $pass);
my $schema_ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(@ua_args);
$schema_ua->credentials(@creds);
# I believe this proxy call is making my connection
my $soap = SOAP::Lite->proxy($addr, @ua_args, credentials => \@creds);
$soap->schema->useragent($schema_ua);
$soap->uri('http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types');
```

When I run this script, I don't get any errors, so I *think* it's working, but like I've already said, I don't know how to check, other than sending some XML to the Exchange server.  That's what I'm trying to do with loading the **email.xml** file (taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa566013%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)), which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetItem
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
      xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <ItemShape>
        <t:BaseShape>Default</t:BaseShape>
        <t:IncludeMimeContent>true</t:IncludeMimeContent>
      </ItemShape>
      <ItemIds>
        <t:ItemId Id="AAAlAF" ChangeKey="CQAAAB" />
      </ItemIds>
    </GetItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Even though I'm not using this XML--other than loading it into an object--I believe it will fail because the **Id** and **ChangeKey** values were copied from the referenced Microsoft page... not really sure where I can find those values other than somehow on the Exchange server, but I'm not an admin... just a simple user.

My thoughts are that I should be able to use the [SOAP::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/~phred/SOAP-Lite-1.06/lib/SOAP/Lite.pm) call function (`$client->call($method => @arguments);`) to send my XML request, but I'm not even sure if I'm going down the right path.  As you can tell, I'm very scatterbrained on this issue.  If anyone can provide any guidance, I would appreciate that very much.

Also, Outlook is reporting that it's Version 14.3.7, which I believe is Exchange 2010.

Comment: EWS::Client uses XML::Compile and the WSDL file for the web service. You should look at XML::Compile handles the WSDL file to build these classes. There is a way to call any of the functions in there, and you want `GetUserAvailability` as the blog post says. If I read the code for EWS::Client correctly, you need to build a new role. Check out EWS::Client::Role::GetItem and FindItem. Try going from there. I think it should not be too hard to patch the stuff you want in. Maybe also contact the author to submit a patch to him.

Comment: Ok, awesome.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I will be doing that once I get home.  I'm a little curious about how EWS::Client works though... I tried poking around in the code, and I couldn't find any XML (other than the Exchange WSDL) that was sent by the user.  So when I grabbed my calendar appointments, did it actually hand off an XML request?  I just couldn't find anything like that in the code... maybe I'm just bad at finding things, or maybe it is all classed based and I just don't understand how it works.

Comment: It sends XML requests allright, but it's based on XML::Compile. I'm not that familiar with how it works, but Mark Overmeer (the author) has given several talks about it on YAPCs. There should be a recording of the YAPC::EU 2012 talk that should clear up how it works. I remember it vaguely. Also, I find your problem quite intruiging and would try it myself if I had more time. Running a current Exchange and all, this could be interesting for me as well, i.e. to sync certain events to Google.

Comment: Ok, awesome.  I'm currently doing this on non-work time, so I have to find the time to do it as well, but I will let you know what I turn up after doing more research.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Get yourself a copy of SoapUI (http://www.soapui.org) for testing your SOAP calls. It'll save you loads of time testing the SOAP calls.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to take a deeper look into that.  Thanks for the info.  I have since turned away from a Perl solution to a PHP solution... which is rather ugly code at this point, but I understand it a lot easier and was able to get data back within a couple of hours of working with it.